# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibility' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function CheckavailOnload()
{
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('box-collateral box-related');
  for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
  if(elems.style.visibility == 'visible')
  {
     var av = document.getElementsByClassName('availability in-stock');
     for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     av[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }
  else
  {
     var av = document.getElementsByClassName('availability in-stock');
     for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     av[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }
 }
}
CheckavailOnload();
```

here i am trying to check the visibility of div "box-collateral box-related" if it is visible i want to toggel the visibility of another paragraph with class name "availability in-stock"

Comment: Well right off the bat, syntax highlighting shows you are missing a quote... `'hidden'`. Although that could just be a copy paste error...

Comment: and check the type of the nodes before assigning attributes to them. Some nodes don't have attributes at all =)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error is coming

Comment: @gee - Did you see my comment on the missing quote?

Comment: At the same time i want to move upward another div if'box-collateral box-related' visiblity is hidden

Comment: ya i added the missing quote but and i uploaded the script but new scripting file is not showing during debugging

Comment: this code is not working please any one can tell me or i have to check the display condition also

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` always gives you a HTMLCollection object, even if it had only one member. HTMLCollection object doesn't have `style` property, hence you need to iterate `elems` in the first `if` to check the visibility, just like you've done further in your code.

If you're sure there's only one member, you can check it's visibility by using `elems[0].style.visibility`.

If you want to check the visibility of a particular element, you can give it an `id` and get that element using `document.getElementById()`.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for a fiddle, now we can have some results.

So, maybe you don't need that `id`, the actual problem occurs when trying to get `style`, if it's not explicitely assigned. To tackle this, you need to use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle):

```
function CheckavailOnload() {
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('box-collateral box-related');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (getComputedStyle(elems[i]).visibility == 'visible' || getComputedStyle(elems[i]).display == 'block') {
            alert("hello");
            var av = document.getElementsByClassName('availability in-stock');
            for (var j = 0; j < av.length; j++) {
                av[j].style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
        else if (getComputedStyle(elems[i]).visibility == 'hidden' || getComputedStyle(elems[i]).display == 'none') {
            var av = document.getElementsByClassName('availability in-stock');
            for (var k = 0; k < av.length; k++) {
                av[k].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        }
    }
}
window.onload = CheckavailOnload;
```

This code will check all elements assigned to classes `box-collateral box-related`. A working demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCT6h/4/).

Notice also use of `window.onload`, which makes sure, that you're not trying to get elements before they are parsed. I switched `elems` to `av` in `for...j`- and `for...k` -loops, supposed to work correctly, if there were different number of elements in `elems` and `av`.

If the first found element with maintioned classes is the one to check, you can simply replace `i` with `0` in all `elems[i]` expressions.

If you want to check only a particular element, you can give it an `id`, and get a reference to it with [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById). In HTML:

```
<div id="checkThisOnly" class="box-collateral box-related">
```

And then in the script:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('checkThisOnly');
if (getComputedStyle(elem).visibility...) {
    ......
}
```

Comment: At the same time i want to move upward another div if'box-collateral box-related' visiblity is hidden

Comment: ?????... Just add `[i]` after `elems` --> `if(elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible')`. When you create `elems` with `getElementsByClassName` it's not just a some element, it's a collection of elements, even if it had only one element, it's still an array-like object. Please take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList

Comment: i have to mention only classname because i dont have id of that both th div

Comment: ya you can see my code on http://jsfiddle.net/7EGSm/14/ just check and please tell me how to do id i dont have id for that elements

Comment: i saw your code its not toggeling the visiblity of paragraph tag deppending on visibility of div with class ="box-collateral box-related"

Comment: I think that's because `div` has `display:block` "by nature". Leave it out from the condition, or use `&&` instead of `||`, though this way you need to set `display:block/none` in your stylesheet too.

Comment: ya you are correct when that element is present then div have display: block;

Comment: do i need to set visibility of both the element in CSS

Comment: do you feel av[j].style.visibility = 'visible'; is correct can i set like this

Comment: Yes, you can do that, it's a valid way to set a style for an element. I think your original question now has a valid answer. Please feel free to accept the one most helped you, and rather post a new question for new problems.

Comment: when div is not present what do you think about the property of that element i am asking about visibility and block property

Comment: one big problem i cant set display:block because it'll disturb my elements in that div without that even our example is also not working http://jsfiddle.net/LCT6h/42/

Comment: Please use either `visibility` or `display`. A `hidden` element can still has `display:block`, if it is not explicitely set to `none`. A working example with toggle button: http://jsfiddle.net/NdDfL/1/ As you can see, there's only one property used, when using more, they have to be set accordingly also.

Comment: in our case we have to add that element through our manage catlog products means through our magentogo site then only that elements will be available otherwise there will be no tag of that div name so how i can set explicitly set to hidden in that case what i can do please reply soon if possible

Comment: If there's no tag, you don't need to hide it either. `getElementsByClassName()` will only find existing elements ofcourse, and this is not supposed to be a problem. As I maintioned before, it's better to post a new question, since we are not discussing about the original subject anymore.

Comment: then getElementByClassName() will return null value?.why i am disscussing because its not working in my code

Comment: Please post a new question with relevant code for the issue, this has nothing to do with your original question (`Uncaught TypeError...`) : ).

Comment: Thanks Teemu i resolved my error your cose is also helpfull to me.once again thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

"elems" is a set of elements yet you try to look at its "style" property.   You need to rearrange things so you loop through elems and then check the property on each one.

Also on your later loops through av - you are looking at elems.length for the scan.  I think this is a bit confused.

Comment: Correct. `getElementsByClassName()` always returns an array of elements, even if only one found.

Answer (score 0):

So, as I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938562/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-visibility-of-undefined#comment19218995_13938562), you seem to be missing a quote around the word "hidden". I'm going to assume that it's a copy paste error.

---

Here is a stripped down version of your code that demonstrates one way to achieve your goal -

```
function Checkavailability()
{
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('box-collateral box-related');
  for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    if(elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible'){
      // do some stuff
    }
    else{
       // do some stuff
    }
  }
}
```

The main difference here is that we are *itearating* over all of the elements that `getElementsByClassName` returns. Note the plural in the function name -

> [get​**Elements**​ByClassName - Returns a set of elements which have all the given class names.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error is coming